# How can we resolve the sales order filter with sku gaves "Something went wrong with processing for sku colum....." in Mageto 2

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, order-grid, sku

The Sales Order Grid Not Working And It's Gives this kind of error when search by sku

> "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have
> restored the filter to its original state."

[image]

in exception.log file i found this king of error.

> [2022-02-11 06:08:55] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
> found: 1054 Unknown column 'sku' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT
> COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`sku` LIKE
> '%GGM6001%') {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code:
> 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sku' in
> 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS
> `main_table` WHERE (`sku` LIKE '%GGM6001%') at
> /mnt/data/home/489837.cloudwaysapps.com/wxvjjsqbbs/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110,
> PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
> Unknown column 'sku' in 'where clause' at
> /mnt/data/home/489837.cloudwaysapps.com/wxvjjsqbbs/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"}

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is wrong. Because their is no column like sku in sales_order_grid table.
Your query should be like below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_order_grid AS main_table WHERE (SELECT sku from sales_order_item where main_table.entity_id=sales_order_item.order_id AND sku LIKE '%GGM6001%')
```

First run your query in table manually than implement in your file.
Hope this help you.

[image]

Comment: no this query not work for me

Comment: What output came after implementing this query in your table?

Comment: shred out put above

Comment: It perfectly working for me. If you are still getting same error then please check query because your error represent that their are no column like SKU in sales_order_grid  and you are trying to fetch it. So once again check query given by me because it working fine for me.

Comment: my sales order grid table not present sku column

Comment: Yes exactly. Because of that you are getting error.Once again try query given by me.